# Stop VBA code and void or cancel all it has already processed?

Tags: vba, excel

I understand that an "on error" code can be used if an error occurs. However, I wonder if it is possible to void all that had been processed by that macro? Perhaps recalling the last memory?

For example, I have a code that runs to transfer many different tasks. Is there a code that can be used to undo what it has done other than manually going to those sheets or files and delete them manually?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It depends what "transfer many different tasks" means. Are tasks rows on a sheet and you re copying them elsewhere? The only rollback feature that I'm aware of is CTRL-Z - maybe you can script that. A better approach may be to ensure that your process can be rerun in any state without creating duplicates

Comment: That is what I am preventing the duplicates. Let's just say the user won't remember what other task it does hence will not be able to retrieve and manually delete all of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save a copy of the workbook to a backup as it starts the code, on error rename the current workbook to something else, restore the backup over the original then close the renamed one you are in.

Open the file again and it will be exactly as it was before you ran the macro.

NOTE, THIS WILL BE SAVING YOUR FILE WHEN IT RUNS, Make sure you have a backup somewhere else when doing your testing.

Comment: you mean, something like at the beginning the code will save the current file and on error recall that file again?

Comment: i recall that excel can recall the last cell occupied on a sheet may be I'll try around that. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: You can find the last cell changed or whatever but to undo all changes it would be much simpler to just save a temporary copy of the book at the start of a routine. There's no magic in-built functions to create a "restore" point of some sort, which basically would do the exact same thing anyway, and ctrl+z doesn't work with events shot from vba. This answer is really the best option.

Comment: There are other ways to do this, I have in the past done this when I was writing to the database I would write out to a sheet (log) the lines of data as I wrote them to the database, if I needed to reverse what I did because the user interrupted it with esc or if the process failed, it would run a cleanup process which would del from the database anything I had in that log. Doesn't sound like this will work in your scenario as you are writing to sheets but it would be simple to tag each new line with an identifier then delete the tag on successful completion or delete the rows on failure.